# Synchronizing with Window Object deletion

Tags: firebreath

I have a plugin which has a content stream pushed to it from an external service which I then draw into a PluginWindowlessWin.

I maintain a reference to the PluginWindowlessWin object so that I can call Invalidate() when new content arrives. However, in certain circumstances (e.g., plugin object removed from the page), the PluginWindowlessWin object is deleted without notifying my plugin. Thus, I end up calling Invalidate() on a bad pointer and crashing.

How can I continue to notify the browser of updates so it will continue to send refresh events - through Invalidate() calls or otherwise - without relying on objects that may be silently deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a windowless plugin, you can't draw except when the browser requests it. Sounds like you have that part.  You can ask the browser to request a draw by calling InvalidateWindow on the PluginWindowlessWin.

Once AttachedEvent is called on your plugin, PluginWindowlessWin will be available; you can even save the reference if you want.  However, you need to release it when DetachedEvent is called.

Comment: Thanks for the response - let me clarify the issue based on this (I'll update the question also). You seem to suggest that the PlguinWindowlessWin object is guaranteed to remain valid until DetachedEvent is called.

However, if, for example, the plugin is removed from the page, the  destructor deletes the PluginWindow object. Thus my saved reference is no longer valid, despite not receiving an detached event.

How should I be handling this?

Comment: If the plugin is removed from the page, the whole plugin shuts down -- and a DetachedEvent *should* be fired before shutdown anyway.  If somehow that's not happening, that's a bug and you should file an issue with the FireBreath team with details and a sample project.

Comment: The DetachedEvent is firing - I had my breakpoints sent poorly and missed it when debugging. The underlying issue is mine - I failed to release a handle in a particular circumstance. Thanks for your assistance.